# I want to get the output in the form of HH:MM:SS, so for example get 5 seconds to be expressed as 05 seconds? Python

Tags: python

Ive written this code and ive obtained the desired output however it is not in the correct format. Essentially the codewars challenge was to take a number of seconds up to around 350000 and then split it into hours then minutes then seconds. For example my code would take x seconds then express it as y:z:p (where y, z and p represent single digit integers) however i would like my code to express it as 0y:0z:0p unless y,z or p are already two digit integers.

Here is my code:

```
secs = 350000
mins = secs/60
hrs = mins/60 
hrs_hol = int(hrs)
print(hrs_hol, hrs)
hrs_rem = hrs-hrs_hol
print(hrs_rem)
mins_from_hrs_rem = hrs_rem*60
mins_hol = int(mins_from_hrs_rem)
mins_rem = mins_from_hrs_rem - mins_hol
secs_from_min_rem = mins_rem*60
secs_final = int(secs_from_min_rem)
H = str(hrs_hol)
M = str(mins_hol)
S = str(secs_final)
print(H+':'+M+':'+S)
```

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the assignments to H, M & S then:

```
print(f'{hrs_hol:02d}:{mins_hol:02d}:{secs_final:02d}')
```

Here we use an f-string and a format specifier that indicates a minimum of two digits (left-padded with zero if necessary)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
H = str(hrs_hol).zfill(2)
M = str(mins_hol).zfill(2)
S = str(secs_final).zfill(2)
```